# Azure DevOps VSTest@2 does not generate code coverage

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, vstest, coverlet

I'm trying to generate code coverage and publish it using Azure DevOps pipelines.

Prerequisites:

- My .NET version is 4.8
- the coverlet.collector package is added to test projects
- NUnit is used.

Here is the task I'm trying to produce coverage report with:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: "Run unit tests and analyze coverage"
  inputs:
    platform: "$(BuildPlatform)"
    configuration: "$(BuildConfiguration)"
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\*UnitTests.csproj'
    searchFolder: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
    resultsFolder: 'C:\temp\TestResults'
    runSettingsFile: 'Redacted\Solution\Redacted.runsettings'
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
    publishTestResults: false
```

My runsettings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
                <Configuration>
                    <Format>Cobertura</Format>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Parts of logs which should be relevant:

```
...
2024-02-09T16:54:26.6295429Z DtaExecutionHost version 19.234.34524.1.
2024-02-09T16:54:26.9607038Z Starting TestExecution Model...
2024-02-09T16:54:31.0217094Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2024-02-09T16:54:31.1426722Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2024-02-09T16:54:31.1524406Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2024-02-09T16:54:31.2868265Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2024-02-09T16:54:31.2868899Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3030070Z Provided settings file:
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3046512Z <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3046955Z <RunSettings>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3047230Z     <DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3047530Z         <DataCollectors>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3047860Z             <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3048281Z                 <Configuration>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3048572Z                     <Format>Cobertura</Format>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3048860Z                 </Configuration>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3049138Z             </DataCollector>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3049397Z         </DataCollectors>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3049696Z     </DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3050000Z </RunSettings>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3218580Z Updated Run Settings:
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3219071Z <RunSettings>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3219348Z   <DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3219631Z     <DataCollectors>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3219974Z       <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3220301Z         <Configuration>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3220594Z           <Format>Cobertura</Format>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3220870Z         </Configuration>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3221124Z       </DataCollector>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3221394Z     </DataCollectors>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3221679Z   </DataCollectionRunSettings>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3221979Z   <RunConfiguration>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3222260Z     <BatchSize>1000</BatchSize>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3222619Z     <ResultsDirectory>C:\temp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3222978Z   </RunConfiguration>
2024-02-09T16:54:31.3223229Z </RunSettings>
...
```

Also there's these:

```
...
2024-02-09T16:54:34.6478537Z Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'XPlat code coverage'.
2024-02-09T16:54:34.6479232Z Data collection : Could not find data collector 'XPlat code coverage'
...
```

After sucessfull test run as a result I get only `trx` file and no `xml` report I need.

- Initially I tried using `Microsoft.CodeCoverage` package with `friendlyName="Code Coverage"` in the runsettings, behaviour was exactly the same.
- I repalced `.dll` with `.csproj` in `testAssemblyVer2` arg, as per some related answers.
- experimented with `publishTestResults` and `codeCoverageEnabled` args, to see if they affect anything.

At this point I'm out of ideas, and hope someone can at least point me in some direction.

Comment: may i know if there's any update? Please follow the reply below for a check. Does the dotnet test command works for you?

Comment: dotnet test will not work for me as my solution uses .NET 4.8, not Core.  I set codeCoverageEnabled to true, and that didn't affect the results. Unfortunately, I have to work on other things.

Answer (score 0):

For the `VSTest@2` task, typically it should use `test files` not csproj as the `testAssemblyVer2` value, also need to **enable** `codeCoverageEnabled`. You need to build the project firstly to generate the test files.

Please check the [task guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) for the details.

[image]

For your scenario, you can use `dotnet test` instead of `VSTest@2` task. Yaml sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--configuration Release --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: |
      $(Agent.TempDirectory)\**\coverage.*.xml
```

[image]

My .runsettings is same with yours. My test project file for your reference:

[image]